# Probability of selecting q red balls from m red balls and n blue balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are $m$ red balls and $n$ blue balls in an urn. We randomly choose $p:m<p<n$ balls uniformly from the urn. What is the probability that exactly $q$ red balls are chosen?

Note:- Normally the answer would be $\frac{{m}\choose{q}}{{m+n}\choose{q}}$. However, since the number of balls that are chosen are provided, it is confusing me out. Any hints for the answer will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is a [Hypergeometric Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) of sampling without replacement.

It follows that

$$P(X=q)=\frac{{{m}\choose{q}}{{n}\choose{p-q}}}{{{m+n}\choose{p}}}$$

Comment: This is true for a given $p$, but $p$ ranges from $m+1$ to $n-1$, so there is still work to do.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I don't think the range of the variable p matters here.

Comment: I think it does.  Suppose $q=1$.  Then (if $n,m$ aren't too different) the probability of success will be higher if $p$ is at the small end of the range.  So I think you need to use the fact that the distribution is uniform over the range, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: @RossMillikan I interpreted the question to mean that there is a given $p:m\lt p\lt n$ but I see now that that would be an assumption but it must be true for any given sampling.

Comment: I am coming to your reading.  In any case your expression is correct for a given $p$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.  Take $q=1,m=2,n=6$ for example.  For $p=3,5$ the probability of one red ball is $\frac {{2 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2}}{8 \choose 3}=\frac {30}{56}$.  For $p=4$ it is $\frac {{2 \choose 1}{6 \choose 3}}{8 \choose 4}=\frac {40}{70}.$  The average of these if $\frac {23}{42}$, but your expression yields $\frac 14$.  Dale M gives the correct expression for a given $p$.