# Help solving probability problem

Tags: probability

A box contains $200$ balls and $10$ of them are red. I need to pick up $20$ balls. What is the probability that $4$ of them are red?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Questions extremely similar to yours have been asked before, see for example this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422414/probability-of-selecting-q-red-balls-from-m-red-balls-and-n-blue-balls. If you want help from others, please consider adding your own thoughts and a reason why the other existing questions do not answer yours fully.

Answer (score 0):

As always, the probability of an event is the number of favorable cases divided by the total number of cases. In your example:
$$P(\text{picking 4 red balls})=\dfrac{\text{(# ways of picking 4 red balls)}\times\text{(# ways of picking 16 non-red balls)}}{\text{(total # ways of picking 20 balls)}}$$
Therefore:
$$P=\dfrac{\binom{10}{4}\binom{190}{16}}{\binom{200}{20}}\simeq 0.00937$$
where $$\binom{n}{p}=\dfrac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$$ is the number of ways to choose $p$ elements out of $n$ elements.